# iterate jsonarray returned by getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

How to iterate JSON array? Console output:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index1' of undefined
>       at Object.success (index.html:29)

Format in variable`data`:

```
[{"index1":2325,"proto_name":"SSH","byte_count":8523026},
 {"index1":2325,"proto_name":"HTTP","byte_count":2123844},
 {"index1":2325,"proto_name":"ab", "byte_count":232}
]
```

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function LoadTraffic() {
        $(function() {
            var url = "traffic";

        $.getJSON( url,
            function(data){
                for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
                    var result = data[i];
                    var $tr = $('<tr/>');
                    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.index1));
                    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.proto_name));
                    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.ts));
                    $('.list-order tr:last').before($tr);
                }
           });
       });
    }

    setInterval( LoadTraffic, 5000 ); <!--1s-->

</script>
```

Comment: You code looks OK, what error messages are you getting?

Comment: What is the specific problem and question?

Comment: Please add some debugging, like `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` before the `for` loop, and `if (!result) console.log('undefined result at ' + i)` just after assigning to `result`, and tell us what you get.

Comment: index1 is integer, is it ok to call `$tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.index1));`?

Comment: Well, `data` is undefined. check URL, or maybe the `type of` `data` is something, not `object` or has no element by name `index1`.
actually, the data is the problem.

Comment: @trincot undefined result at 13

Comment: @easa console outputs the right jsonarray format in `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))`.

Comment: OK, so clearly entry 13 (start counting from 0) is somehow missing from that array. If you cannot give the actual output of that log, then you'll have to debug yourself. Maybe you have other code in the loop which you have not shared which redefines `i`... or maybe you mutate `data`...

Comment: @user7328234 break on console and check. maybe the `type` is a string?

Comment: I will post the whole code.

Comment: What is the value of `data.length`?

Comment: the code is ok. all the matter is what `data` is?
please log `typeof  data` at the first line of function.

Comment: @easa your comments don't make sense. `$.getJSON` will not pass a string to the completion callback